# Ошибка AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo' в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\program\rubik\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/program/rubik/cube.png")
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4130, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4063, in __init__
    master = _get_default_root('create image')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 319, in _get_default_root
    raise RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window")
RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000002E86DDEF380>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 132, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import ImageTk

im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/program/rubik/cube.png")
im2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/program/rubik/Cube1.png")

room=Tk()
room.geometry('200x200')
room.resizable(height=False,width=False)
room.mainloop()

btn=Button(room, image=im, height=100, width=100)
```

Comment: "RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window" - картинка создаётся до основного окна.

Comment: Сначала создайте окно (объект Tk), потом загружайте изображения

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том что ImageTk.PhotoImage() имеет атрибут master,
если он не заполнен то заполнится автоматически существующим окном Tkinter.
Но так как вы сначала импортируете картинки а окна на тот момент не существует, происходит ошибка

исправленный код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import ImageTk

room=Tk()
room.geometry('200x200')
room.resizable(height=False,width=False)

# images
im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/program/rubik/cube.png")
im2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/program/rubik/Cube1.png")
# ------

btn=Button(room, image=im, height=100, width=100)
btn.pack()

room.mainloop()
```